# Tensorflow Bazel Build Core dumped error on RPI 3

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, raspberry-pi3, image-recognition, bazel

I am trying to build Tensorflow NoGPU from source on my RPI 3. I'm following [samjabrahams](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md#1-install-basic-dependencies) tutorial to compile Bazel. But When I run ./compile.sh, it freezes(Or maybe some background work) at **Building from Scratch** for more than 45 mins and tells that Bazel couldn't be compiled. After reading the error message I could extract keywords like **'Core dumped'**, **'HeapOutOfMemory'** and also It has mentioned somewhere that **name doesn't match repository name(Maybe SDK path)**. I am new to this and couldn't figure out the exact problem after searching for hours. Need some help.

I'm trying again to compile. Will post the exact error message when I get one.

Here is the error message where everything failed.

```
INFO: Loading package: src/java_tools/buildjar/java/com/google/devtools/build/\
buildjar/genclass
scripts/bootstrap/compile.sh: line 311:  8234 Trace/breakpoint trap   "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xverify:none -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 -XX:HeapDumpPath=${OUTPUT_DIR} -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${OUTPUT_DIR}/javalog.properties ${JNI_FLAGS} -jar ${ARCHIVE_DIR}/libblaze.jar --batch --install_base=${ARCHIVE_DIR} --output_base=${OUTPUT_DIR}/out --install_md5= --workspace_directory=${PWD} --nofatal_event_bus_exceptions ${BAZEL_DIR_STARTUP_OPTIONS} ${BAZEL_BOOTSTRAP_STARTUP_OPTIONS:-} $command --ignore_unsupported_sandboxing --startup_time=329 --extract_data_time=523 --rc_source=/dev/null --isatty=1 --ignore_client_env --client_cwd=${PWD} "${@}"
+ fail 'Could not build Bazel'
```

Comment: It seems you're running out of memory, did you apply all the fixes from the tutorial?

Comment: @mhlopko I tried what all I could find. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the swap memory as said in the GUIDE does the job, worked for me. After doing the steps mentioned by samjabrahams, check the swap space by `free -h`.

If you're booting to Pi in GUI then, go to `sudo raspi-config` and change boot option to CLI. It will give you more free RAM. If pi reboots, check the swap memory, if not around 1 GB execute `sudo swapon /dev/XXX` replace XXX with your device id. Make sure you have added `-J-Xmx500M` flag.

(Optional)
Below commands improved performance for me while building bazel and tensorflow. It improves swap memory utilization.

```
sysctl -w vm.swappiness=15
sysctl -w vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_ratio=15
sysctl -w vm.dirty_ratio=20
```

I've built tensorflow for raspberry pi 3 binary for python3.5, will save you time from building. [Raspberry Pi 3 - Tensorflow 1.2.1](https://github.com/akashjobanputra/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/releases/tag/v1.2.1)